# MySQL Error 1064 when creating foreign key

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I created this using MySQL WorkBench

```
ALTER TABLE `android_marketplace`.`ban_utilizator` 
DROP INDEX  ,
ADD INDEX `ban_utilizator_id_utilizator_idx` (`id_utilizator` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `android_marketplace`.`ban_utilizator` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `ban_utilizator_id_utilizator`
 FOREIGN KEY (`id_utilizator`)
 REFERENCES `android_marketplace`.`utilizatori` (`id_utilizator`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

I am getting this :

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the 
database.
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `android_marketplace`.`ban_utilizator` 
DROP INDEX  ,
ADD INDEX `ban_utilizator_id_utilizator_idx` (`id_utilizator` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `android_marketplace`.`ban_utilizator` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `ban_utilizator_id_utilizator`
 FOREIGN KEY (`id_utilizator`)
 REFERENCES `android_marketplace`.`utilizatori` (`id_utilizator`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
ADD INDEX `ban_utilizator_id_utilizator_idx` (`id_utilizator` ASC)' at line 2
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `android_marketplace`.`ban_utilizator` 
DROP INDEX  ,
ADD INDEX `ban_utilizator_id_utilizator_idx` (`id_utilizator` ASC)
```

Comment: What index would you like to drop?

Comment: consider adding the currently existing index name on line 2:
`DROP INDEX  index_name,`. If you have no index yet, remove `DROP INDEX ,` line.

Comment: I don't want to drop a index, I want to add a foreign key... I deleted that drop index and now works, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with a foreign key.

You must name the index you want to drop.

Syntax error messages include the context of the problem. If the syntax error says:

> check ... for the right syntax to use near '
>   ADD INDEX `ban_utilizator_id_utilizator_idx` (`id_utilizator` ASC)'

This means the syntax was expecting to find something else at the point where you provided `ADD INDEX`.

In this case, it was expecting a name for the index you tried to drop in the clause immediately preceding `ADD INDEX`.